# Why not create and delete 'TABLE' whenever data inserted?

Tags: database-design

I have argued with my friend for DB schema.

Our app reads a kind of csv file, and then inserts data(almost 200 rows) into table.
Sometimes the app needs to delete data by filename.

So, i suggest folloing table schema -> [Key], [Text], [FileName]

it is able to insert data with filename, then delete data by filename(delete from [TABLE] where filename ='boolaboola').

But my friend,
he insists on "Why not create and delete 'TABLE' whenever data inserted?"

His table schema is ->
[Key], [Text]

His idea is
[When the app reads a file, the app creates one table whose name is the filename. Then insert data into the new table.
When we need to delete data by filename, just drop table.]

Even though our table does not need foreign key.

I couldn't agreed with that idea.
In my experience, I felt that DB schema is wrong... 
but I cannot explain and persuade my friend.

Please help me.
Am I wrong? or how can I persuade my friend?

Comment: Does data from *different* files every end up being used in a single query? If so, that *strongly* argues for storing in a single table.

Comment: Just a random thought: If you follow your friend's recommendation How would you search for a particular data and return all the files that contain it?

Comment: In current feature, we will query all file's data or just one file's data..

Comment: Well, how does you friend propose to query all file's data if it's sitting in separate tables?

Answer (score 2):

In general, I agree with you. Changing the database schema should IMHO generally be a rare action, preferably only when the software is updated. I know this is very strict and 'un-NoSQL', but this is a traditional relational database after all :).

For a more specific recommendation, it would help to know how you're intending to use this data. Storing it in one table (perhaps partitioned or with an index on 'filename' for performance, if that's an issue) is more flexible: it allows you to easily do analyses that span data from multiple files.

Also if you later want to use some kind of O/R-mapper or other tooling, it often helps to have your table schema rather static.

Answer (score 2):

Just for perspective, an example from the real world. Not exactly an "answer", just a story :) I decided to post it because someone said that changing the schema [i.e. creating and dropping tables] should be a rare action". Without giving a satisfactory explanation.

I'm currently working on a big application for a very large corporation. It consists of 80% PL/SQL (Oracle) server-side and 20% browser GUI (Javascript, based on Yahoo's excellent YUI3 library). The GUI alone has >140 individual modules.

The (larger) server-side part of the application unfortunately has no middleware, it is all written in PL/SQL. That's because years ago it was a small app where this architecture was just fine, and you never get funds to write a version "2.0" (which means starting from scratch, throwing away the 1.0 code). (Even so, given the limitations, it's surprisingly well-written, even though many PL/SQL functions exceed 1000 lines or even more by now).

So, while your web app middleware routinely keeps track of sessions and session data, all of this had to be done manually in PL/SQL - and we do this by creating LOTS of temporary tables. There are huge amounts of data to handle, and instead of a middleware cache we use tables, for session data as well as for certain functions. For example, when the user enters certain higher-level "use cases" we aggregate (large amounts of very detailed) data into temp. tables, and the user is served from those tables for the rest of his session. Those higher-level use cases don't need the details, they only need the aggregates.

So, creating and dropping tables... well, at least WE do it, and it works fine. There are no general technical reasons for or against it, it depends on your REAL WORLD situation. Purists can complain about our lack of a middleware all they want, for example, in the real world complaining doesn't get anything done.

I suggest to try to look at the greater picture. Why are you against dynamically creating tables? Are the reasons really technical, then defend your position with as much force (and cunning) as you can. However, too often we tech. guys are waaaayyyyyyyy too religious and refuse to acknowledge it (to ourselves first of all).

When you find yourself arguing forever (with another "techie") without anyone being able to convince the other it may be an indicator that the issue just isn't that important, because there simply is no obvious and justifiable answer :) Religious discussions are always much longer than technical ones ;-)

Creating and dropping tables dynamically is a "legit" use case. When the data is used only temporarily (instead of stored "forever") and if you run queries only against the set of data in that temp. table (if it's cross-table there's a heavy argument against the temp. table(s)), go for it - if it's convenient in the grand scheme of things (your app and overall scenario).

*PS: Oh and by the way, just generally speaking, no way to say much about the scenario given here, performance as an argument should only enter into this if it REALLY is an issue. For 95% of all situations it isn't, maintainability is far higher on the list.*

Answer (score 0):

Dropping tables increases performance because the table won't have to be reindexed and other DB engine overhead; this greatly improves performance on large data. However, creating multiple tables increases your code complexity, since you'll have to use an index of your own to find the right table on querying.